# jQuery .css border-radius does not work with position:absolute?

Tags: jquery, image, position, rounding, css

I have a series of images that makes a gallery-type of display.  I use jQuery to make them round with a random diameter for each.

It works perfectly fine, but then I need to place them correctly. The problem is that giving the `<div>` that contains the image a `position:absolute` (or any kind of position) turns the `<div>` back into a square.

Is there a fix?  Am I doing something wrong?

I made a [Fiddle to make the code clear.](http://jsfiddle.net/simuse/szGnh/15/)

Comment: they look like circles to me (Chrome 13). What browser are you using?

Comment: Circles to me too. 4 Circles to be exact. :) That's in Chrome. In FF there are 4 squares.

Comment: Answer posted below... did it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Putting a wrapper `<div>` around each image, seems to solve it...

http://jsfiddle.net/szGnh/21/