# jQuery validate - require_from_group duplicating error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form and it has three pairs of start/end dates. For each pair I validate if both inputs are filled out or none of them are filled out because it's not allowed to fill out a start date and doesn't the end date and vice-versa, plus, I can't send the form without at least one of the pairs filled out.

The validation for each pair works just fine, but the rule supposed to validate if at least one of the three pairs is filled out duplicates the error message in the first and the last fields of the form.

I wrote a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgioseffi/QF5tt/) to exemplify the problem. I want one message only to be displayed and not two as it's happening. What I'm doing wrong?

Other doubt, can I use the require_from_group to validate the pair instead of validating each one of the six inputs?

**EDIT StackOverFlow if forcing me to put some code since I provided a fiddle. You can ignore it because it's already in the fiddle.**

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="msgErros" class="mensagens_erro"></div>
<form>
    <table width="95%" id="tabela_interna">
        <thead><tr valign="middle"><th colspan="6">Report</th></tr></thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr valign="middle">
                    <td width="14%" align="left" class="td_label"><label for="dataInicialSolicitacao">Data de Solicita&ccedil;&atilde;o Inicial</label></td>
                    <td width="25%" align="left" class="td_dados">
                        <input type="text" name="filtro.dataInicialSolicitacao" size="12" value="" id="dataInicialSolicitacao" class="data atLeastOneRequired"/>
                    </td>
                    <td width="12%" align="left" class="td_label"><label for="dataFinalSolicitacao">Data de Solicita&ccedil;&atilde;o Final</label></td>
                    <td width="25%" align="left" class="td_dados">
                        <input type="text" name="filtro.dataFinalSolicitacao" size="12" value="" id="dataFinalSolicitacao" class="data atLeastOneRequired"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="middle">
                    <td width="14%" align="left" class="td_label"><label for="dataInicialLiberacao">Data de Libera&ccedil;&atilde;o Inicial</label></td>
                    <td width="25%" align="left" class="td_dados">
                        <input type="text" name="filtro.dataInicialLiberacao" size="12" value="" id="dataInicialLiberacao" class="data atLeastOneRequired"/>
                    </td>
                    <td width="12%" align="left" class="td_label"><label for="dataFinalLiberacao">Data de Libera&ccedil;&atilde;o Final</label></td>
                    <td width="25%" align="left" class="td_dados">
                        <input type="text" name="filtro.dataFinalLiberacao" size="12" value="" id="dataFinalLiberacao" class="data atLeastOneRequired"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="middle">
                    <td width="14%" align="left" class="td_label"><label for="dataInicialInternacao">Data de Interna&ccedil;&atilde;o Inicial</label></td>
                    <td width="25%" align="left" class="td_dados">
                        <input type="text" name="filtro.dataInicialInternacao" size="12" value="" id="dataInicialInternacao" class="data atLeastOneRequired"/>
                    </td>
                    <td width="12%" align="left" class="td_label"><label for="dataFinalInternacao">Data de Interna&ccedil;&atilde;o Final</label></td>
                    <td width="25%" align="left" class="td_dados">
                        <input type="text" name="filtro.dataFinalInternacao" size="12" value="" id="dataFinalInternacao" class="data atLeastOneRequired"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br />
    <div style="width: 95%; text-align: center">
        <button class="margem_botoes" id="gerarRelatorio">Consultar</button>
        <button class="margem_botoes" type="reset">Limpar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**The JS:**

```
String.prototype.contains = function(sub) { return this.indexOf(sub) != -1; };

$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        "filtro.dataInicialSolicitacao": { require_from_group: [1, ".atLeastOneRequired"], ifDateIsFilledOtherOneIsMandatory: "#dataFinalSolicitacao", maximunDifferenceBetweenDates: ["#dataFinalSolicitacao", 90] },
        "filtro.dataFinalSolicitacao": { require_from_group: [1, ".atLeastOneRequired"], ifDateIsFilledOtherOneIsMandatory: "#dataInicialSolicitacao", maximunDifferenceBetweenDates: ["#dataInicialSolicitacao", 90] },
        "filtro.dataInicialInternacao": { require_from_group: [1, ".atLeastOneRequired"], ifDateIsFilledOtherOneIsMandatory: "#dataFinalInternacao", maximunDifferenceBetweenDates: ["#dataFinalInternacao", 90] },
        "filtro.dataFinalInternacao": { require_from_group: [1, ".atLeastOneRequired"], ifDateIsFilledOtherOneIsMandatory: "#dataInicialInternacao", maximunDifferenceBetweenDates: ["#dataInicialInternacao", 90] },
        "filtro.dataInicialLiberacao": { require_from_group: [1, ".atLeastOneRequired"], ifDateIsFilledOtherOneIsMandatory: "#dataFinalLiberacao", maximunDifferenceBetweenDates: ["#dataFinalLiberacao", 90] },
        "filtro.dataFinalLiberacao": { require_from_group: [1, ".atLeastOneRequired"], ifDateIsFilledOtherOneIsMandatory: "#dataInicialLiberacao", maximunDifferenceBetweenDates: ["#dataInicialLiberacao", 90] }
    },
    messages: {
        "filtro.codigoProcedimento": { range: "Por favor, insira um valor entre 1 e 9223372036854775807 ao preencher o cartão." },
        "filtro.codigoHospital": { range: "Por favor, insira um valor entre 1 e 9223372036854775807 ao preencher o estipulante." },
        "filtro.codigoSegurado": { range: "Por favor, insira um valor entre 1 e 9223372036854775807 ao preencher a solicitação." },
        "filtro.numeroSolicitacao": { range: "Por favor, insira um valor entre 1 e 2147483647 ao preencher o referenciado." }
    },
    groups: {
        datasSolicitacao: "#dataInicialSolicitacao #dataFinalSolicitacao",
        datasLiberacao: "#dataInicialLiberacao #dataFinalLiberacao",
        datasInternacao: "#dataInicialInternacao #dataFinalInternacao"
    },
    onfocusout: function (element, event) {
        if (!$(element).attr("class").contains("data")) {
            $.validator.defaults.onfocusout.call(this, element, event);
        }
    }
});

$.extend($.validator.messages, {
    require_from_group: $.format("Por favor, preencha ao menos {0} uma das duplas de datas para realizar a consulta.")
});

$.validator.setDefaults({
    errorContainer : "#msgErros ul",
    errorLabelContainer: "#msgErros",
    wrapper: "li"
});

$.validator.addMethod("trim", function(value, element) {
    return value.length > 0 ? $.trim(value).length > 0 : true;
}, "Por favor, entre com valores diferentes de apenas espaços para o campo.");

$.validator.addMethod("ifDateIsFilledOtherOneIsMandatory", function(value, element, param) {
    var target = $(param);
    if (this.settings.onfocusout) {
        target.unbind(".validate-ifDateIsFilledOtherOneIsMandatory").bind("blur.validate-ifDateIsFilledOtherOneIsMandatory", function() { $(element).valid(); });
    }

    return !(!isDateEmptyOrFilledWithMask(target.val()) && isDateEmptyOrFilledWithMask(value));
},"Por favor, forne&ccedil;a a outra data deste par final e inicial de datas.");

$.validator.addMethod("maximunDifferenceBetweenDates", function(value, element, param) {
    var startDate;
    var endDate;
    if (param[0].contains("Final")) {
        startDate = value;
        endDate = $(param[0]).val();
    } else {
        startDate = $(param[0]).val();
        endDate = value;
    }

    return areBothDatesFilled(startDate, endDate) ? (($.datepicker.parseDate("dd/mm/yy", endDate) - $.datepicker.parseDate("dd/mm/yy", startDate)) / 86400000) <= param[1] : true;
}, $.validator.format("Por favor, forneça uma diferen&ccedil;a de no m&aacute;ximo {1} dias entre as datas."));

function areBothDatesFilled(firstDate, secondDate) {
    return !isDateEmptyOrFilledWithMask(firstDate) && !isDateEmptyOrFilledWithMask(secondDate);
}

function isDateEmptyOrFilledWithMask(date) {
    return date == "" || date == "__/__/____";
}

$(".data").mask("99/99/9999").numeric().datepicker().attr("maxlength", 10);

$("form").on("reset", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).clearForm();
    $("#respostaRelatorio").jqGrid("GridUnload");
    $(".erasableInfo").empty();
    $("#msgErros").empty();
});
```

Comment: SO is nagging you for code because when jsFiddle links go dead your question becomes totally useless to future readers.  Please don't ignore that message.

Comment: jsFiddles go dead? I can see a very old link of a fiddle I wrote.

Comment: Yeah... they go dead. I saw an old answer of mine with a 404 fiddle link just yesterday.  I guess you don't remember the jsFiddle website ever going dead either... it happens.

Comment: Do you know how much time they keep the link alive? I have this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pgioseffi/8Ur8N/ that I wrote over a year ago.

Comment: **The links stay alive _until they don't work anymore_.**  Here's one of mine [from a 2011 SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7030965/594235) that's no longer any good to anyone:  http://jsfiddle.net/szGnh/21/

Comment: Could you be more specific? What do you mean by "don't work anymore"?

Comment: I simply meant that you and I could never possibly have any idea how long a third party web page will be left online.  It's only online at the leisure of jsFiddle; until they decide to take it down; until it's purged, until it crashes... etc. etc.  I think we've beat this horse to death or perhaps there's some kind of language barrier.  Either way, take this topic over to meta.stackoverflow.com if you want to discuss it further.

Comment: No need to, finally I got it what you meant. I just wanted to know the rule for them to kill a fiddle and I thought you knew it, but as you said: "we've beat this horse to death".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `groups` option is commonly used in conjunction with the `require_from_group` method.  It will combine all the error messages into one for the specified fields.  Then you can use CSS and/or the `errorPlacement` option to position the message to your liking.

```
groups: {
    someArbitraryName: "fieldName1 fieldName2 fieldName3"
}
```

See documentation:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate

Comment: I'm using groups with the require_from_group method. I don't need the error placement because I use $.validator.setDefaults({
    errorContainer : "#msgErros ul",
    errorLabelContainer: "#msgErros",
    wrapper: "li"
});. This is in the code I provided, BTW. Were you able to check the fiddle? Could you edit it to a correct approach?

Comment: @Philippe, if you have three different groups of fields then they all can't use the same class, `atLeastOneRequired` inside the `required_from_group` rule.  By using the same class on all six, the plugin thinks all six are in the same group.  You'll need three different classes to distinguish your three different groups.  After all, how do you expect it to know you have three groups?  No, the `groups` option does not connect to the `require_from_group` rule at all.  The `groups` option is only used for combining messages.

Comment: I'm sorry for keep you waiting a answer, but by the time you responded I had already left work and then came the weekend and so I couldn't test your suggestion. These six dates should be in the same group, if I do your way the plugin forces me to fill out at least one of the start date or end date of the pair, but my use case forces me to have at least one of the pairs filled out, got it?

Comment: @Philippe, I'm sorry, I don't think I can decipher your problem description.  [I've answered almost 30 questions using `require_from_group` including working demo code](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A594235+require_from_group).  Perhaps you'll find the answer somewhere in there.

Comment: were you able to take a look at the fiddle? If you check it, you'll see a table with three rows, my form can't be submitted if at least one row is fully filled out, plus, if a row is partially filled out the form can't be submitted either, in other words, I have to have a require_from_group per row. I'm brazilian and maybe I'm not making myself clear because of my English. Am I clearer now?

Comment: @Philippe, perhaps I'm not making myself clear.  Yes, there is definitely some kind of language barrier... did ***you*** look at the link I provided in the last comment?

Comment: Yes, I did, maybe this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20616972/how-can-i-validate-a-group-within-another-group-and-maintain-separate-error-mess/) is near from what I need. Still, with require_from_group I'm able to force that at least two fields have to be filled out in the six fields group, but with this rule I can't garantee that a row is fully filled out.

Comment: What do you think if I use skip_or_fill_minimun on each row and require_from_group on all three rows? The first one assures me that if I fill out one of the fields of the row, the other field of the row will become mandatory. Having this rule respected on each row will assure that require_from_group will only be executed in the case that no field is filled out.

Comment: I've wrote my code the way I explained in my last comment and validation works fine and most of the messages too. I wrote another version of the first [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgioseffi/QF5tt/7/). Could you take a look and tell me why the messages get triplicated when I try to submit a blank form? Maybe it's a problem with the groups I created and if you check it, maybe you find out what's happening. The messages are displayed where I want, but they are repeated three times. The first problem that was duplicating the messages was because I had been using the inputs ids and not the names.

Comment: I found out the last problem too. The group "todos" has to be in the last place for the messages don't triplicate themselves. But if I write the code it this way, the "todos" group will override the other groups that are subgroups of itself, in other words, if a user just enters start dates I **do** want three messages instead of just one. Could you help me with that or do you want me to create another question and explain the problem a little longer? Plus, I accepted your answer because the problem is that I wasn't using the input names.